# Where to find Firefox's internal files in order to fix bugs?

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox Nightly, so sometimes I find a bug. In those cases I file a bug in [bugzilla.mozilla.org](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)

But I would like to help a bit more. Since I am good at JavaScript and I have seen that some patches affect javascript files, I think maybe I would be able to help fixing some bugs.

But the problem is that I don't know where can I find those files. I have tried renaming `omni.ja` to `omni.jar` and decompressing it, and some folders coincide but most don't, so I can't find the files that I want to modify in order to try to fix the bug.

Some examples:

- `browser/devtools/scratchpad/scratchpad.js`
- `browser/components/customizableui/src/CustomizableWidgets.jsm`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial

Comment: @Zoredache Does that mean I have to download full source code and recompile Firefox? Since I only want to modify JS files, I thought that there was no need to compile anything.

Comment: @Oriol - The answer to your question is, yes, you will need the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to extract the `omni.ja` in the Firefox root folder (as you already did) along with the `omni.jar` in the `browser` folder. In fact I was able to find both the files you asked for with `find`:

- `scratchpad.js` is in `chrome/browser/content/browser/devtools/scratchpad.js`
- `CustomizableWidgets.jsm` has a different path because it is a [Javascript Code Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules), and you can find it in the `modules` folder.

However, keep in mind that to repack the `omni.ja` files you have to specify particular parameters to the `zip` command. The [MDN wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_%28formerly_omni.jar%29) recommends:

```
zip -qr9XD omni.ja *
```

So yeah, it would be better to recompile Firefox from the source tree instead of editing the runtime files. Also see [this](http://mike.kaply.com/2013/05/06/dont-unpack-and-repack-omni-jar/).

Comment: Oh, there's another `omni.ja`! Will it work if, instead of building a new `.jar`, I just add (with winrar) the modified file to the existing `.jar` and rename it to `.ja`? I think this should maintain the required configuration, without needing `-qr9XD`

Comment: I'm not sure if it will, because -X and -D are quite particular options: `-X   eXclude eXtra file attributes` `-D   do not add directory entries`. However, you can try to make a backup of the original jar, make the edits you want and then try it (restore the backup if it doesn't work).

Comment: Code references JSM files with the `resource://` prefix, and [it appears that you can't override resources](https://mike.kaply.com/2013/05/06/dont-unpack-and-repack-omni-jar/#comment-253796).